# Mouse over event and cursor pointer on the line series

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have the following implementation and it is functional. When user clicks on the line series, then it loads another data.

I want to give an impression to the first time user that line series clickable with implementing `mouse over event` and `cursor: pointer`.

```
var isHover=false;
function onClick (e) {
   if (!isHover) {
        var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
        chart.options.series =[{data: stats2,name:stats2[0].name}] ;
        chart.redraw();
        isHover = true;
   }
  else if (isHover) {
        var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
        chart.options.series = [{data: stats,name:stats[0].name}];
        chart.redraw();
        isHover = false;
       }
}
```

### **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3yhbyy2g/73/)**

Comment: can't you use `circle { cursor: pointer; }`?

Comment: @chazsolo, could u please give me an example on the top of current fiddle?

Comment: I've added the CSS [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3yhbyy2g/75/)

Comment: thanks it works, however, I would like to apply cursor pointer on all line series not only for circles as I mentioned in the question  `line series clickable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit hacky, but this should work on stroke as well as the path:

```
circle:hover,
path[stroke="#ff6800"]:hover { cursor:pointer; }
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/3yhbyy2g/78/

But would be better to set a class here (since you are tying the mouseover to a certain color), but not sure how this would work in kendo.

And since it's a bit hard to hit the line, maybe it would be enough to leave it on the circle alone.